# Does CrossGeeks library of Xamarin Geofencing supports beyond Android 9 and latest versions of iOS?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, geofencing

We tried to implement the CrossGeeks plugin on Xamarin.form, but apparently it doesn’t work beyond Android 9. We haven’t checked it on latest iOS versions. If anyone implemented it recently, help me understand how can we make it work on latest Android and iOS versions. Btw, I am not a developer, I am a marketing guy. I got the above feedback from my developer. Thanks…

We wanted to use CrossGeeks to share live location data with our MarTech platform CleverTap, since CleverTap Xamarin SDK doesn’t natively support Xamarin, which is a deprecated platform as well. But we started building our application two years ago and got stuck to Xamarin. Hope it explains…

Comment: this is not CrossGeeks support.  If you have questions about which platforms they support, I suggest you contact them.